# Import pandas module gives Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pandas, attributeerror

I recently changed from Windows to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I am trying to get the hang on Python.

I copied a couple of example commands from 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html
into a .py file called pandas.py

This file was created in my home directory /home/myname

Here is an excerpt with the first 14 lines of /home/myname/pandas.py:

```
# pandas.py

###################################
## Testing out the pandas module ##
## Last update: Jan 2014         ##
## Author: me                    ##
###################################

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a Series by passing a list of values,
# letting pandas create a default integer index
s = pd.Series([1,3,5,np.nan,6,8])
```

when trying to run the script (using IDLE), I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myname/mypandas.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/myname/pandas.py", line 14, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Series'
```

it appears as if Python tried to import my .py file rather that the actual module.

The same error appears if I write

```
import pandas
```

on my Python Shell. I changed the file name to mypandas.py, deleted the previous file, cleared the trash bin, and rebooted. This error just keeps appearing.

Other libraries such as numpy import just fine. I imagine there is some shell command which reverts this situation, but I am still not quite acquainted to Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete compiled script, `pandas.pyc`, from the location of your script, that is from your home directory. And don't name your scripts the same names as modules you're using.

Comment: Missed that .pyc file, now it works just right. And yes, Im never naming a .py file after a module ever again :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar error regarding the 'compat' attribute, restarting kernel helped

Comment: This is more a comment than an actual answer. Please have a look at [How to write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)