# How can I load both PyQt4 and pandas in the same program?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt

Using this simple example to illustrate my point:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import pandas as pd

print('Hello, there')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testQtError.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 4789, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:107900)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 4707, in pandas.tslib.TimeRE.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:78495)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 4590, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__init__ (pandas\tslib.c:75782)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 4610, in pandas.tslib.LocaleTime.__calc_weekday (pandas\tslib.c:76222)
AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'day_abbr'
```

After some research, I'm lead to believe that the error is because probably both the PyQt4 and pandas modules are doing a `import calendar` somewhere, and it's conflicting. Or, rather, one or both have their own `calendar` class defined that conflicts with the python `calendar` module.

update: I've tried deleting my cached files from `__pycache__`dir, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047601/import-pandas-module-gives-attribute-error), however the problem persists.

update2: After reading the linked question from my previous update, I realized I had a file 'calendar.py' in my working  directory. This was the culprit.