# Unable to import pandas module; python prints AttributeError from older python session

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weird issue. Whenever I import pandas, I get an `AttributeError`:

```
import pandas as pd
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_sql_query'
```

That error message is from an old python session when I was playing around with pandas. I'm now unable to load pandas as all, I just get that attribute error. Here's the full stacktrace:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tsd/p19/home/p19-jonasmst/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/cluster/software/VERSIONS/python_packages-2.7_3/cluster/software/VERSIONS/python2-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_stream
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    asid_occurrences = pd.read_sql_query(sql_find_asid_occurrences, db)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_sql_query'
```

Possibly relevant info:

- I'm on a cluster and have to load python2 as a module in order to import pandas.
- I'm logged in to a Linux VM on the cluster through a Thinlinc client (via FireFox), from which I'm again SSHed into another Linux VM.
- I've tried `module purge` and then `module load python2` again, to no avail.
- I've tried to log out from the VM and back in again, to no avail.
- I was using VIM when I first got the `AttributeError`.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? Thanks!

**Update:**
This seems to happen only when I'm in the directory where I got the error earlier. Moving to another directory allows me to import pandas just fine. There are no hidden files or anything in that directory, though, so I don't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my script was called `parser.py` which probably conflicts with something in pandas. [Similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047601/import-pandas-module-gives-attribute-error?rq=1)